# Exit from app when click button in android phonegap?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am new to phonegap. I have prepared one sample application. My application has 2 pages, the first page has one button, when clicked the second page will open. It is working fine using the following

```
         function callAnothePage()
         {
            window.location = "test.html";
         }
```

The second page has one button, when clicked I want to exit from the application. I used the following

```
       function exitFromApp()
       {
            navigator.app.exitApp();
       }
```

`test.html` code,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.0.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">  
        function onLoad()
        {
            console.log("device reday !!!!")
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true);
        }
        function exitFromApp()
        {
            console.log("in button");
            navigator.app.exitApp();
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body onload="onLoad();">
    <h4><center>Login Page</center></h4>

    <input type="submit" onclick="exitFromApp()" value="exit"/>

</body>
</html>
```

But it is not working.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Try this code.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>PhoneGap</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.5.0.js"></script>      
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

            function onLoad()
            {
                  document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true);
            }

            function exitFromApp()
             {
                navigator.app.exitApp();
             }

        </script>

    </head>

    <body onload="onLoad();">
       <button name="buttonClick" onclick="exitFromApp()">Click Me!</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Replace **src="cordova-1.5.0.js"** with your phonegap js .

Comment: Replace with phonegap-1.4.1.js but not working and i got error like,   " Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'exitApp' of undefined at file:///android_asset/www/test.html:16"

Comment: @user1651572 Please download the latest version of phonegap js . It solved your problem .

Comment: can u please send me url for latest version . I goggled for latest js file i am not able to find....

Comment: can i know what is difference b/w cordova.js and phonegap.js

Comment: @user1651572 before that it phonegap.js now its cordova. Nothing else

Comment: added cordova-2.0.0.js and still i got error like cannot call method exitApp

Comment: @user1651572 take button instead of input type and check agian

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'exitApp'

Comment: @user1651572 . Try this navigator.device.exitApp()

Comment: This only minimises the app on Android 8. It doesn't close it fully :S

Comment: As of 2019, iOS ignores all attempts to exit. If it does close it's considered a "crash" since it goes against the developer guidelines.

Answer (score 21):

There are different ways to close the app, depending on:

```
if (navigator.app) {
    navigator.app.exitApp();
} else if (navigator.device) {
    navigator.device.exitApp();
} else {
    window.close();
}
```

Comment: This is a nice way, thanks! Actually, I'd add a typeof check if exitApp is really a function (not sure if this would be present in all cases where navigator.app or navigator.device exist)

Answer (score 11):

```
navigator.app.exitApp();
```

add this line where you want you exit the application.

Answer (score 3):

@Pradip Kharbuja

In Cordova-2.6.0.js (l. 4032) :

```
exitApp:function() {
  console.log("Device.exitApp() is deprecated. Use App.exitApp().");
  app.exitApp();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if(navigator.app){
        navigator.app.exitApp();
}else if(navigator.device){
        navigator.device.exitApp();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I used a combination of the above because my app works in the browser as well as on device.  The problem with browser is it won't let you close the window from a script unless your app was opened by a script (like browsersync).

```
        if (typeof cordova !== 'undefined') {
            if (navigator.app) {
                navigator.app.exitApp();
            }
            else if (navigator.device) {
                navigator.device.exitApp();
            }
        } else {
            window.close();
            $timeout(function () {
                self.showCloseMessage = true;  //since the browser can't be closed (otherwise this line would never run), ask the user to close the window
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

sorry i can't reply in comment. just FYI, these codes

```
if (navigator.app) {
navigator.app.exitApp();
}
else if (navigator.device) {
  navigator.device.exitApp();
}
else {
          window.close();
}
```

i confirm doesn't work. i use phonegap 6.0.5 and cordova 6.2.0