# kill webview browser window using javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, phonegap-plugins

In phonegap app all external link opening in default webview browser, i need to give a close button which will close the current window and back to app.
Same thing what a back button do in android.

I have tried `window.close()` but it is not working on app.

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12297525/exit-from-app-when-click-button-in-android-phonegap) help?

Answer (score 2):

A good approach for external links is to open them using the [in-app-browser](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser) plugin. This ensures all external links open nicely across multiple devices. It also makes it easier to open and close external links.

For example opening an external link on iOS can often result in not being able to get back to your app. The [in-app-browser](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser) plugin resolves that issue.